# Web browsers cannot save files other than to the default location in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, snap, chromium, 22.04

This issue is probably related to others but so far I haven't seen a proper solution.

UPD: I checked that `xdg-desktop-portal-gnome` (for gnome and gtk, as well) is already installed and hence the problem is different from the bug explained here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1970148

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, all browsers don't allow to save files to any folder other than set by default. The problem appears in both **Chromium** and **Firefox** installed using `snap`, but also in a stable **Chrome** version from `.deb` package.

The issue is probably *not relevant to parent directory*: if I switch the default saving location, e.g. from `/home/USERNAME/Downloads` to somewhere on the mounted `/media`, the download is allowed there, but not to other places, including `/home`. I as well tested this on all three browser installations.

There are also problems on opening files, e.g. Firefox tend to crash on `Ctrl+O`, even while hovering over files, but I suspect this issue is different, perhaps related to `snap`.

I saw an advice to disable Wayland but I prefer not to do the former for now.

Comment: It's a known bug that is currently being worked upon: [LP #1971168](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1971168). The developers intend to fix the bug rather than offer a workaround.

Comment: Do you mean `/home/` or do you mean `/home/$USER/`   ? You probably can't save to `/home/` because your user doesn't have permission. `/home/` is owned by root. `/home/$USER/` is owned by your user.

Comment: @mchid - yes, I meant the user's parent directory

Answer (score 0):

I use Firefox 103 install from source file tar.bz2 extract to /opt/ can save file in partition mount. If use firefox from snap or apt-get repo can't save file in partition mount